# div percentage not working with parent

Tags: html, css

This is my code. I want the background of #splash to be 90% of the page.

```
a, span, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
a, a:focus, a:hover, a:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
}
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner{
    width: 85%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
#splash{
    height: 90%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

and HTML

```
<html>

<body>
    <div id="splash">
        hi
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6KGk/

I looked into it and saw that the parent `body` had to be 100% as well. Although, it is still not working so I don't know.

Thank you very much for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the 'html' element before your body in the css, and it will work ;-)

```
html, body {
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the parent of `body` - `html`. If you set `height: 100%` to it you will get what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/KAgS9/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#splash{
    height: 90%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```